In Power Bi Visualisation, I have used slicer for dropdown but the option for dropdown selection is not showing in visualisation. Showing as a tile
In Power Bi, I want dropdown value but its showing tiles format instead of dropdown by using Slicer option. In slicer settings not getting any option to select dropdown.
I have tried as a after selecting slicer, in slicer setting its not showing dropdown option in Power Bi, it showing value as a Tiles Format.
Please help

I think you may be using "Slicer (new)" , check you are using the "Slicer" instead.

in the visualization panel, under format visual, select Slicer settings, in the Options field, choose Dropdown in the drop down list
Screenshot

I have tried all these using powerBi Desktop but i think version issue or something, after that i have implemented dropdown using Slicer PowerBI Web instead of powerBI desktop.

@PraveenRichhariya -- Easiest if you setup this Dropdown option first, RIGHT AFTER ASSIGNING THE FIELD/COLUMN to the slicer.  (Start over, if you have to.)  Then hover over the slicer, and look below the ellipsis (the 3 dots), to see a little downward-facing CARET (like a down-arrow).  Clicking on that down-caret, there are at least 2 options:  List and Dropdown. But after formatting the slicer, that down-caret is often not visible.  IT'S STILL THERE -- hovering just slightly below the ellipsis, you're prompted to Select the type of slicer.  But it's harder to find or click.
